# coming back from a fadeOut in Jquery

Tags: javascript, visibility, fade

In the following code, div's are faded out using the new fadeOut functionality of Jquery. Unfortunately, this changes the style of the tag to "display:none". And I can not figure out how to change it back, so that I can Fade it in.

I do not want to use the opacity style, or fadeTo, because I need the divs to be completely hidden, pulling all other floating divs up with it.

```
/* Hide interface, fade logo */
$('.toggle-ui').on({
    'click': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var divToHide = ['#slideshow-nav', '#nav', '#content'];

        $.each(divToHide, function(intValue, currentElement) {
            // check alpha state and switch
            var currVis = $(currentElement).css('visibility');

            $(currentElement).css('visibility', currVis == 'visible'
                ? $(currentElement).fadeOut('slow')
                : $(currentElement).fadeIn('slow'));
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

checking for the style "display" and using that for the conditional works.

As follows:

```
$('.toggle-ui').on({
    'click': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var divToHide = ['#slideshow-nav', '#nav', '#content'];

        $.each(divToHide, function(intValue, currentElement) {
            // check alpha state and switch
            var currDis = $(currentElement).css('display');

            $(currentElement).css('visibility', currDis == 'none'
                ? $(currentElement).fadeIn('slow')
                : $(currentElement).fadeOut('slow'));
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I answered at the same time (you can do that). Posted it up so people can see. It works. What mistakes are you talking about?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value : `value` must be either a string or a number, `.fadeIn/Out()` returns a jQuery object. Then, I think `.fadeToggle()` would be enough, no need for this `currDis == 'none'` check.

Comment: Glad for you, but your answer is likely to lead others to the wrong direction since it contains a few mistakes.

Comment: I think i will leave it up regardless. Thanks anyway.